# Freeform form description in user notification emails

Tags: solspace-freeform

How do I add the form description to a user notification email template?
I can't see a list of available variables in the documentation, but just about all other variables are listed on the side of the template editor in the CP.
I tried {form_description}, but that didn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{form_id} is available and you can use the {exp:freeform:form_info} tag pair as all EE template tags are available now in Notifications as of Freeform 4.

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form_info/

But you are correct, we are missing documentation on available variables for notifications. I have made a note for us to create them. Our apologies.

Comment: What about {freeform:description:FIELD_NAME}?

I can't seem to use the field description in my email notifications?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   What about {freeform:description:FIELD_NAME}? I can't seem to use the field description in my email notifications? – Third_Hyperion Aug 17 '16 at 10:34

I have this issue too. Is this possible?